# Opening new activity with fixed width and height in android

Tags: android

I am creating an enterprise app on android 2.3 which is like the default launcher app with some modifications. The home and back button of the device is hidden behind an enclosing, thus a user won't be able to click them. My problem is that: once users launch an app from the launcher then how do I give them an option to go back (as they wont be able to click the back button of the device). I was thinking of inserting a bar at bottom with a button - clicking on which takes the user back, more like what happens in Android 3.0.
 **So my question is:** Is there a way to limit the height and width of launched activity and also can I show a bar with a button on it below other activities?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the layout you can add the some header or footer kind of bar.some thing like this..

[image]

Comment: I want to show the bar over any application and not just my own. Since I won't be able to change the layout of other apps I need a way to open them in a fixed window size and show the bar either above or below the app.

Comment: It is not possible to set for all applications.u can set only for particular application which u r designing.